# Simple database design

Tags: database, database-design

I am so poor on database design. I want to ask you to make sure !
Example I have two table look like this:

```
1)                  2)
tb_users:      |      tb_users:
----------     |     -------------
- user_id      |      - user_id
- user_name    |      - user_name
- role_id      |    ===============  
============   |      tb_role:
tb_roles:      |    --------------
-----------    |      - role_id
- role_id      |      - role_name
- role_name    |      - user_id
============   |   ================
```

Which one is right, 1) or 2)?
Thank for any answer. I really don't understand. If you have any key to remember, please tell me also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one, but read this whole answer please for a comment at the end.

Look at it this way: "Users" can stand alone. They do not need roles. However, "Roles" require users or they have no meaning.

Having said that, I think both are wrong. The third option is to have 2 main tables, and a 3rd table that allows you to join the others.

The User table uniquely identifies users. The Role table identifies roles. The User_Role table says which user has which role.

So something like this:

```
USER
----
User_Id
User_Name

ROLE
----
Role_Id
Role_Name

USER_ROLE
---------
User_Id
Role_Id
```

That allows for each user to have as many roles as required, and it allows for roles to be assigned to as many users as required.

Comment: Thank you a lots MJB, because it's short and meaningful for me.